# Angular 7 build error - licenseType.indexOf is not a function

Tags: angular, angular7

I get the following error when I build the angular application using `--prod flag`.It builds fine when I am not using that flag (code works fine on `ng serve`):

```
licenseType.indexOf is not a function
TypeError: licenseType.indexOf is not a function
    at LicenseTextReader.readLicense (D:\e\todoListFront\node_modules\@angular-devkit\build-angular\node_modules\license-webpack-plugin\dist\LicenseTextReader.js:29:40)
    at PluginChunkReadHandler.processModule (D:\e\todoListFront\node_modules\@angular-devkit\build-angular\node_modules\license-webpack-plugin\dist\PluginChunkReadHandler.js:52:62)
    at D:\e\todoListFront\node_modules\@angular-devkit\build-angular\node_modules\license-webpack-plugin\dist\PluginChunkReadHandler.js:29:23
    at WebpackModuleFileIterator.iterateFiles (D:\e\todoListFront\node_modules\@angular-devkit\build-angular\node_modules\license-webpack-plugin\dist\WebpackModuleFileIterator.js:7:9)
at D:\e\todoListFront\node_modules\@angular-devkit\build-angular\node_modules\license-webpack-plugin\dist\PluginChunkReadHandler.js:27:32
    at WebpackChunkModuleIterator.iterateModules (D:\e\todoListFront\node_modules\@angular-devkit\build-angular\node_modules\license-webpack-plugin\dist\WebpackChunkModuleIterator.js:21:21)
    at PluginChunkReadHandler.processChunk (D:\e\todoListFront\node_modules\@angular-devkit\build-angular\node_modules\license-webpack-plugin\dist\PluginChunkReadHandler.js:26:29)
    at _loop_1 (D:\e\todoListFront\node_modules\@angular-devkit\build-angular\node_modules\license-webpack-plugin\dist\WebpackCompilerHandler.js:48:37)
    at WebpackCompilerHandler.iterateChunks (D:\e\todoListFront\node_modules\@angular-devkit\build-angular\node_modules\license-webpack-plugin\dist\WebpackCompilerHandler.js:71:17)
    at D:\e\todoListFront\node_modules\@angular-devkit\build-angular\node_modules\license-webpack-plugin\dist\WebpackCompilerHandler.js:29:27
    at AsyncSeriesHook.eval [as callAsync] (eval at create (D:\e\todoListFront\node_modules\tapable\lib\HookCodeFactory.js:32:10), <anonymous>:14:1)
    at AsyncSeriesHook.lazyCompileHook (D:\e\todoListFront\node_modules\tapable\lib\Hook.js:154:20)
    at hooks.additionalAssets.callAsync.err (D:\e\todoListFront\node_modules\webpack\lib\Compilation.js:1281:36)
    at _err0 (eval at create (D:\e\todoListFront\node_modules\tapable\lib\HookCodeFactory.js:32:10), <anonymous>:16:1)
    at Promise.all.then.sources (D:\e\todoListFront\node_modules\@angular-devkit\build-angular\src\angular-cli-files\plugins\scripts-webpack-plugin.js:127:17)
    at <anonymous>
```

Comment: Can you please post your code where using indexOf?

Comment: did you try ng build --prod --no-extract-licenses?

Comment: Thanks for the reply guys.I updated my package and it works fine now

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

```
npm i --save-dev @angular-devkit/build-angular@0.10.3
```

Apparently the issue is in a dependency of `0.10.2`. `0.10.3` references a version in which the issue has been resolved.